# Send Message to discord from changes in Formulated Cell in Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, discord, urlfetch

I have formulated all cells in my Google Sheet, but since they are not counted as edits (since it is formualated update and not manual edit), I am not receiving notifications when there are updates in the value of the cell. Is there a way to set up notifications for updates in a Google Sheet, regardless of whether the cells are edited or not?

In Addition, Can I send the notification of these update in Discord/Whatsapp/Telegram?

Thanks.

I tried set up with zapier, iftt, etc. But it doesnt work since it is not edited.

To put context of the code below:
I want to run in tab "Sheet1" and whenever value changes in Column L, update me in discord (would be great if someone can help edit the code to just run the cell value as message in Discord)

```
function onChange(e) {
  // Get the active sheet in the Google Sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  // Set the range to the entire sheet
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();

  // Set the value of e to the active sheet
  e = {range: range};

  // Send a notification to Discord when the range L:L is changed
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == "L:L") {
    // Replace YOUR_DISCORD_WEBHOOK_URL with your own Discord webhook URL
    sendDiscordNotification("xxx", "New booking testing.");
  }
}

// Sends a message to a Discord webhook
function sendDiscordNotification(webhookUrl, message) {
  var payload = {
    "content": message
  };
  var options = {
    "method": "post",
    "payload": JSON.stringify(payload)
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(webhookUrl, options);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Per site guidelines, please [edit] the question to limit it to only one question. Also, what do you mean by "Is there a way to set up notifications for updates in a Google Sheet, regardless of whether the cells are edited or not?" Are the spreadsheets formulas dependent on other cells? If the cells aren't edit, what updates are done on the spreadsheeet?Please add a [mcve].

Comment: Upon a cell edit, a function can be triggered. In order to have a wider scope, instead of using the names `onEdit()` or `onChange()`, use another name an install a trigger for that function. Changes in cells which are formula-based do not trigger functions. An alternative would be to set up a trigger to run at a certain frequency. That would send the msg and mark it as sent in an adjacent column, so that it doesn't send it again next time it runs.

Comment: @Rubén my question is just one, and it is quite straightforward tbh, formulated cell is not counted as "edited by xxx" in spreadsheet, thus, i cannot trigger it to give me notification on "changes of value in cell whenever formula trigger". No need minimal reproducible example as it is simple straightforward question. "Formulated cell, whenever changes in value, send as discord messages"

Comment: @onit I cannot do per frequency update as it is a database of a booking system, thus, it has to be auto replied instantly as some people book 2 minutes before their game time.